# Visual Studio 2012 not able to debug non-x64 .net applications: Access Violation

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, access-violation, visual-studio-debugging

I upgraded (clean install) from Win7+VS2012 to Win8+VS2012.

I ran into a problem just after that: When I try to run any project with the processor target *AnyCPU* or *x86*, vshost.exe crashes immediately after building and starting the project with an *Access Violation*. This behavior is not affected by changing the type of the project (console, winforms, wpf).

When I change the architecture to *x64* however, debugging works just fine.

This is the output I get in the Debug output window if I start a new created console application:

```
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'e:\Users\SeriTools\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe', Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', Symbols loaded.
The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x1068) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x16c8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1688) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x233c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'e:\users\seritools\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe', Symbols loaded.
The program '[5088] ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[5088] ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

What I tried to fix that:

- Completely removed and reinstalled VS, checking if not applying Update 1 changes anything
- `devenv.exe /ResetSettings` and uninstalling all plugins/add-ins
- running VS as admin

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: If you get AV exception on x86 and not on x64 I would guess that you are setting value to a variable, which its size is dependant on architecture, such as `void*`. Another idea: try debugging this with WinDBG. Might give more usefull information. Regarding `AnyCPU` - my guess is that in this case it is alternating to 32-bit architecture, probably due to the architecture of the module that loaded it.